# Rewriting kernel using Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

Show (using the Fourier transform) that
$$
K(u) = \frac{1}{2} \exp \left(- \frac{|u|}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \sin \left(\frac{|u|}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\pi}{4} \right)
$$
can also be written
$$
K(u) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi t u)}{1+(2\pi t)^4}   \, \mathrm{d}t.
$$

I have no idea how to proceed. Any thoughts or hints?

EDIT:

I've accepted Mark Viola's answer since it was very helpful and, I assume, even more so if you're familiar with complex integrals. I ended up using a different approach myself though:

Noting that $K$ is symmetric, the Fourier transform can be written
$$
\mathcal{F}(K) = \int K(u) \cos(u \omega) \, \mathrm{d}u . 
$$

Using symmetry of $K(u)\cos(u\omega)$ and the product-to-sum trigonometric identity: $2\sin x \cos y = \sin( x+y )+ \sin (x-y)$, we get
$$
\mathcal{F}(K) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \exp \left(-\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \sin \left( \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \omega \right] u + \frac{\pi}{4} \right)\, \mathrm{d}u \\
 +  \frac{1}{2}  \int_0^\infty \exp \left(-\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} \right) \sin \left( \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \omega \right] u + \frac{\pi}{4} \right)\, \mathrm{d}u  .
$$

Using the integral formula, derived by change-of-variables and partial integration,
$$
\int_0^\infty \exp(-ax)\sin(bx+c) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\cos(c)b+\sin(c)a}{a^2+b^2}
$$
we get that
$$
\mathcal{F}(K) = \frac{1}{1+\omega^4}.
$$

Now applying the inverse Fourier transform yields the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note from even symmetry that $K(u)$ is the Fourier Transform of $\frac1{1+(2\pi t)^4}$ with Fourier kernel $e^{i(2\pi u)t}$.  That is to say that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi ut)}{1+(2\pi t)^4}\,dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i2\pi ut}}{1+(2\pi t)^4}\,dt$$

Now, determine the inverse Fourier Transform of $K(u)=\frac12 e^{-|u|/\sqrt 2}\sin\left(\frac{|u|}{\sqrt 2} +\frac\pi4\right)$.

Can you proceed now?

Comment: Additional hint, $$\sin\phi=\frac{e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}}{2i}$$

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still quite confused - How does computing the inverse Fourier transform help?

Comment: @Lundborg The Fourier Transform pair are unique.  So, if you can show that the inverse transform of $K(u)$ is $\frac{1}{1+(2\pi t)^4}$, then it must be true that the Fourier Transform of $\frac1{1+(2\pi t)^4}$ is $K(u)$.  Is that clearer now?

Comment: @MarkViola You've been incredibly helpful but I think my problem is perhaps more fundamental, I'm not really used to computing Fourier transforms at all and get very confused by the resulting integrals over complex exponential functions.

Comment: Well, note that $$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-(|u|/\sqrt 2)}e^{\pm i(|u|/\sqrt 2+\pi/4)}e^{i2\pi t u}\,du&=e^{\pm i\pi/4}\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-\frac{|u|}{\sqrt 2}(1\pm i)+i2\pi t u}\,du\\\\
&=e^{\pm i\pi/4}\int_{-\infty }^0 e^{\frac{|u|}{\sqrt 2}(1\pm i)+i2\pi t u}\,du+e^{\pm i\pi/4}\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-\frac{u}{\sqrt 2}(1\pm i)+i2\pi t u}\,du
\end{align}$$Can you proceed now?